# Transferring from Windows to Linux OS for ESRI ArcReader

Tags: linux, arcreader, arcgis-publisher

I have a .pmf file and I would like to open it under ubuntu. However all the layers are directing to a C:/ source. As Linux OS does not have such drive, how can I change the layer source path? Thanks!

Edit: I only have ArcReader with me..... Is it a must that I need to use a editor to output a new .pmf again for linux OS?

Comment: Can you cheeck by any chance if relative paths were used when authoring a map document in ArcMap? Because if you want to distribute data together with the published document, you need to use relative paths when you create the map (map document file > Map Document Properties). So, if you are using relative paths, the published map will be able to access the data as long as it stays in the same location relative to the GIS datasets.

Comment: it points directly to C:\ drive in Windows.... i.e. C:\map\data.mdb.... So I was wondering how to get the link working under Linux...

Comment: I am afraid then that the only way to repath the published document is to re-publish it in ArcMap with the Publisher extension enabled and use relative paths to the data (since you cannot provide the access to the source data).

Comment: Thanks to Alex Tereshenkov, yes, it seems (and I end up) the only way is to use ArcMap to publish the document again....

Comment: I have wrapped my comments to the answer, so it will be neat. Feel free to accept it. PS. You have mentioned .mdb (personal geodatabase file) in the path above. Just curious, did you make it work for ArcReader on Linux?

Comment: Yes, they got Linux ArcReader 10.1 for Linux on ESRI 's website :)

Comment: no I meant did the personal geodatabase work on Linux (that you used in the path)? It is a MS Access file and I was wondering if ArcReader has ability to read MS Access files on Linux.

Comment: well.... it was kind of messy, the map was built from a previous guy and I am new to ESRI.... the map was partially built from mdb, I exported those data and then imported them again to the map (they changed to .dbf, .shp etc). Then I did data packaging... which only allowed me to use data format: copy data in existing format..... and by the way, I'm using Arcmap 9.3.1

Comment: Ah, I see. You are using shapefiles then, not the personal geodatabase format. Then it should work fine. Good luck with the work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If when authoring a map document in ArcMap relative paths were used then you could just replicate the location of the data on the Linux machine. This is a common practice for distributing .pmf files.

So, if you want to distribute data together with the published document, you need to use relative paths when you create the map (use the File > Map Document Properties menu). Then, thanks to using relative paths, the published map file will be able to access the data as long as it stays in the same location relative to the GIS datasets.

However, since you hadn't used relative paths, the only way to manage the data paths with respect to Linux paths, is to re-publish the map document in ArcMap with Publisher extension enabled and set relative paths for the map document beforehand. Alternatively, you could also use absolute paths, but make sure you use the same path you expect to have on the Linux machine.

Esri help page: [About managing data sources for ArcGIS Publisher](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//000s00000008000000)